# Azure Machine learning error

Tags: azure, machine-learning

I am trying to create a Percentage win calculator using a multi class decision forest

I have two data sets one of existing win/loss data and another of pending items (same column structure)  (win/loss/pending are all in one column call status)

the experiment runs no problems on the test data (win/loss) and has about a 90% accuracy rating

but when i move it over to a web service and try to run it with the other data set I get an error "

> Apply Transformation Error Cannot process column "NAICS" of type
>   System.Double. The type is not supported by the module. . ( Error 0017
>   )"

The naic code is no different in one data set than the other

I am lost any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: okay I am getting the impression this might not be the best place to put it but rather than taking a S on my question with no explanation why you downvote maybe tell me where it should go or how the question could be better shaped

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have already known that 0017 means `Exception occurs if one or more specified columns have type unsupported by current module.` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn905850.aspx).
From the suggested resolution, you can do [Convert to Dataset][2]